# When reading in a binary file as a char * buffer, it keep reading it as binary instead of as characters

Tags: c++, binaryfiles, ifstream

```
void reader(string fileName){
     ifstream ifile; 
     ifile.open(fileName, ios::binary | ios::in);
     ifile.seekg (0, ifile.end);
     int length = ifile.tellg();
     ifile.seekg (0, ifile.beg);
     char * buffer = new char [length];
while(ifile.good()){

    // read data as a block:
    ifile.read (buffer,4);
    cout << buffer <<endl;
    //ifile.read((char *)&inputName, sizeof(int));
    //cout << inputName;

}
ifile.close();
```

The output it gives out looks like this:

```
▒d▒▒root.d[$Apd▒▒
endXroot.d
```

when I expect it to look more like

```
root.d
endXroot.d
```

the data was entered into the file as *root.d/0endXroot.d* idk if that helps or not.

Comment: `ifile.read (buffer,4);` reads four bytes. Note that this will not necessarily include a null terminator. `cout << buffer <<endl;`Will print the contents of `buffer` as a null terminated string, which it probably isn't. Chaos ensues. Would answer but I can't  100% explain the `▒d▒▒`.  Possible [byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)?

Comment: How did you create the file? If you open the file with Notepad, is there any extra stuff?

Comment: `std::istream` has two categories of reading methods: Unformatted reads, which just give you the raw bytes, and Formatted reads, which do various conversions and skip whitespace and such.  Which do you need? `istream.read` is an unformatted read.

Comment: I created the file using c++  fstream ofile; 
    ofile.open(file, ios::binary | ios::app);
ofile.write((char*)&numOfFiles, sizeof(numOfFiles)); 
numOfFiles just is one example of a variable I put into it, I added to it in multiple places

Comment: @MooingDuck I want to read it like a string or char array and then analyze that and turn it into classes that I have.

Comment: Is numOfFiles an int? If you do `cout << *(int*)buffer << endl;` do you get the right number, by any chance? If you wrote some numbers in the file then you didn't write *root.d/0endXroot.d*, did you? Because you wrote numbers and that isn't numbers

Comment: If you write an `int` into a file as a binary blob, it's going to come out a the other side as a binary blob. Odds are that `▒d▒▒` is that binary blob.

Comment: Oh yeah I guess the full output id expect is root.d/00endxroot.d

Comment: should i convert the into into a character before adding it to the file?

Comment: Totally depends on what you need to do. In this case it seems you want output as nothing but text. I n that case it stands to reason that only text goes into the file.

Comment: I changed it so that i convert the int to string before hand and now the output is root.dO$A▒▒2▒0▒Ԝ▒▒2▒

Comment: See first comment and note about null-terminated strings.

Comment: How would i prevent null-terminated strings?

Comment: What would be a good way if i just wanted to read in everything from a /0 to another /0 because i was thinking of working it so i have a /0 between every set of things

Comment: You get out what you put in.  If you wrote an int, you can't read a string.  Post the write code and the read code in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ifstream ifile; 
    ifile.open(fileName, ios::binary | ios::in |ios::ate);
    if(ifile.good()){
        char * buffer;
        long size;
        ifstream file (fileName, ios::in|ios::binary|ios::ate);
        size = file.tellg();
        file.seekg (0, ios::beg);
        buffer = new char [size];
        file.read (buffer, size);
    }
 }
```

I fixed it by having it get the size and then reading directly to it. I also fixed underlying issues with how the write was written for the binary file.

Comment: Prefer `std::vector`, since your code has potential memory leaks.